# Android mvvm should I use 2 ViewModels, 1 ViewModel in two views, or 1 in Parent activity?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel

Given the case : ProfileActivity and EditProfileActivity both extend from a BaseActivity, should each activity have their own viewmodel (ProfileViewModel and EditProfileViewModel), use the same viewmodel in the two activities or inherit the model from the parent but obverse it in each activity?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the scope of your ViewModels. If you want your activities to communicate with each other, then you can create a BaseViewModel scoped to your BaseActivity and use that to do IPC among ProfileActivity and EditProfileActivity, given that they expend BaseActivity.

You can also create three viewModels, one for each. Use the BaseViewModel for IPC and the ProfileViewModel and editProfileViewModel for delegation, where the activities will be light themselves and will delegate everything down to their viewModels. This can be achieved through the combination of LiveData observers and DataBinding.